# Azure Cognitive - searchMode=any/all behave differently in one search term query

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to understand what `searchMode` does.

Taking this request as an example (`"searchMode": "any"`):

```
{
  "queryType": "full",
  "search":"plates:/.*003/.*",
  "searchFields": "dates,models,plates",
  "searchMode": "any",
  "highlight": "dates,models,plates",
  "highlightPreTag": "<b>",
  "highlightPostTag": "</b>"
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://lab-cognitivesearch-lab.search.windows.net/indexes('data')/$metadata#docs(*)",
  "@odata.count": 1,
  "value": [
    {
      "@search.score": 1.0,
      "@search.highlights": {
        "plates": [
          "<b>1000003</b>"
        ]
      },
      "dates": [
        "20201231"
      ],
      "models": [
        "model2"
      ],
      "plates": [
        "1000003"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If I simply use `searchMode=all`, it returns nothing.

All the fields in the searching are collection(String) type with no analyzer set (using standard analyzer)

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents)

> Valid values are "any" or "all" Defaults to "any". Specifies whether
> any or all of the search terms must be matched in order to count the
> document as a match.

In the example above there is just one term, so using ANY or ALL should have not make difference. Right?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-simple-examples), "searchMode=any" favoring recall (a document that satisfies any of the criteria is considered a match), and "searchMode=all" favoring precision (all criteria must be matched in a document).

If **searchMode=any**, any one criteria is satisfied then document will be return in search result.

If **searchMode=all**, all criteria should be satisfied then only document will be return in search result.
I have reproduced issue from my side and below are steps I followed,

1. Created a search index in azure cognitive search.
   [image]
2. Using postman, calling search api as shown below,
   Url: https://xxx.search.windows.net/indexes/azureblob-index/docs/search?api-version=2021-04-30-Preview
   Request-type: Post
   Headers: api-key
3. Results when using searchMode as any,
   [image]
4. Results when using searchMode as all,
   [image]

Comment: your example is exactly like mine. Just one criteria (something should be like (exactly or not) something). Are you saying wildcards are not supported in a searchMode=all?

Comment: Yes in case of all, search criteria should match exactly.